# Stop PHP Execution But Display HTML

Tags: php, html

In a Profile page of the User, I want to validate his input with PHP after submission and display errors on the same page before updating in the database.

For this, I'm doing something like:

```
<div>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submitted"])) {
    if (!isValidEmail($_POST["email"])) {
        echo "<p>Please enter a valid email address.</p>";
        return; // or exit;
    }
    if (!isValidPhoneNumber($_POST["phoneNumber"])) {
        echo "<p>Please enter a valid phone number.</p>";
        return; // or exit;
    }
    ...
    if (updateUser($id, $email, $phoneNumber, $name)) {
        echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>");
    } else {
        echo "<p>An error occurred! Could not update your profile information!</p>";
    }
}
?>
</div>
<my-footer></my-footer>
```

So when an error occurs upon PHP validation, the footer doesn't appear. So I understood that with `return` or `exit` the page will stop rendering at that command.

What can I do to solve this issue?

I want it to stop execution of the PHP script but display the rest of the HTML page.

Comment: I think you  should use die(); instead return;

Comment: @Mxxpersian nope, it gave the same result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put your validation logic inside a function at the top of your page, and change all your `echo` to `return`.

```
function validate() {

    if (isset($_POST["submitted"])) {
        if (!isValidEmail($_POST["email"])) {
            return "<p>Please enter a valid email address.</p>";
        }
        if (!isValidPhoneNumber($_POST["phoneNumber"])) {
            return "<p>Please enter a valid phone number.</p>";
        }

        //...

        if (updateUser($id, $email, $phoneNumber, $name)) {
            return "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
        } else {
            return "<p>An error occurred! Could not update your profile information!</p>";
        }
    }

}
```

Then simply `echo` the string returned from the function above the footer.

```
<div>
    <?php echo validate(); ?>
</div>
<my-footer></my-footer>
```

Note that the above will work because `$_POST` is a [`superglobal`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). However, you may consider changing your function to pass `email`, `phoneNumber`, `name` and `id` as parameters instead.

Comment: oh thanks this is probably the neatest solution and I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your flow up a little bit...

```
if (isset($_POST["submitted"])) {
    $has_errors = FALSE;
    $err_msg = '';

    if (!isValidEmail($_POST["email"])) {
        $err_msg .= "<p>Please enter a valid email address.</p>";
        $has_errors = TRUE;
    }
    if (!isValidPhoneNumber($_POST["phoneNumber"])) {
        $err_msg .= "<p>Please enter a valid phone number.</p>";
        $has_errors = TRUE;
    }

    if ( $has_errors ) {
        echo "<p>Please Correct the following and resubmit...</p>" . $err_msg;
    } else {
        if (updateUser($id, $email, $phoneNumber, $name)) {
            echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>");
        } else {
            echo "<p>An error occurred! Could not update your profile information!</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I thought about it or about using `if`, `else if`, `else` blocks.. but I was just wondering whether there is a way in PHP that skips the script. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many times you will see PHP frameworks that can handle this for you.
Here's a good website to compare a few: http://phpframeworks.com/

But what you can do is put your footer (and / or the rest of your code) into a function that holds the rest of your code for you, and you can call it later or whenever you need to so you can still end code execution gracefully.

```
<div>
<?php
function footer() {
    $string = "</div>";
    $string .= "<my-footer></my-footer>";
    return $string;
}
if (isset($_POST["submitted"])) {
    if (!isValidEmail($_POST["email"])) {
        echo "<p>Please enter a valid email address.</p>";
        die(footer()); // Displays footer
    }
    if (!isValidPhoneNumber($_POST["phoneNumber"])) {
        echo "<p>Please enter a valid phone number.</p>";
        die(footer()); // Displays footer
    }
    ...
    if (updateUser($id, $email, $phoneNumber, $name)) {
        echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>");
    } else {
        die("<p>An error occurred! Could not update your profile information!</p>" . footer()); // kills the page execution, but still returns the foot of the page.
    }
}

echo footer();

?>
```

Comment: This works but I think @BA_Webimax 's solution is better in case there was more info to be display other than the `<my-footer>` element. But thanks anyway.